# Firebase AuthUI...signOut() requires phone permission

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Calling `AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this)` to sign-out from Firebase account shows **Google Play Services** "phone" access permission request dialog (if user disabled such permission for any reason).

If user denies to give access sign-out fails:

`com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 17: Error resolution was canceled by the user, original error message: CANCELED: null`

At the same time no phone permission required to sign-in.

1. What could be the reasons to require such permission to sign-out?
2. Is it possible to sign-out some other way without forcing user to give access?

From the google [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#permission-groups), this includes next:

```
READ_PHONE_STATE
READ_PHONE_NUMBERS
CALL_PHONE
ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS
READ_CALL_LOG
WRITE_CALL_LOG
ADD_VOICEMAIL
USE_SIP
PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS
```

I see nothing related to accounts or Firebase in this list, considering that sign-in was using either e-mail or Google account (not phone / SMS). And once again, no permissions was required to sign-in.

ADDED LATER: After debug attempt I found that **signOut()** finally calls **signOutIdps()** that in turn calls **GoogleSignIn.getClient**(context, GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).**signOut()** but no further source code available in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` is that it [clears the user from disk cache](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#signOut()), so you need **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permissions.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. And shouldn't, because it is not my app permissions, but Google Play Services.

Comment: Can you try using exactly the syntax `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();`?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you used FirebaseAuth instead of AuthUI. Now it works, thanks!